# KeyCloak-js and vue3 - Need some pages to be public

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, keycloak, keycloak-js

I'm using keycloak-js adapter with a Vue 3 Application. This system has some public pages, so I can't call keycloak right away. I already setup a button to call the login page, but the token is not being setup in the localStorage.

Basically my user flow need to be: Landing page > Clicks login button > Go to keycloak login page > redirects to a page where i make a request to return the user roles > get the user rows and redirects to the right page.

My request need a token and I can get to the redirection page, but the request fails because I don't have a token or a refresh token. Also, it give TypeError: adapter is undefined error when I try something different

Heres is my keycloak init function. If I change the onLoad option to check-sso, it returns #error=login_required&state=c7d6d227-5b23-4b21-962a-8e6291545f55. So login-required is working for me.

```
const Login = () => {
    KeyCloakInstance.init({ onLoad: "login-required", checkLoginIframe: true, 
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/redirect" })
    .then((authenticated) => {
        console.log("Keycloak Authenticated", authenticated)
        if (authenticated) {
            console.log("Authentication Success")
            KeyCloakInstance.authenticated = true;
        } else {
            console.log("Authentication Failed")
        }

        localStorage.setItem('token', KeyCloakInstance.token as string);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', KeyCloakInstance.refreshToken as string);

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.dir(err);
        console.log("Authentication Failed", err);
    });
}
```

and heres a guard I made for the routes

```
import { getRole } from "@/services/config";
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";

function guardAuth(to: any, from: any, next: any){
    const hasUser = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const isMeta = "auth" in to.meta;
    const metaAuth = to.meta.auth;

    if(isMeta && metaAuth && !hasUser){
        const keycloakInst = new Keycloak({
            url: "http://localhost:8082/",
            realm: "APP",
            clientId: "live_app"
        });

        keycloakInst.login();
    } else if(isMeta && !metaAuth && hasUser){
        RoleType(hasUser, next);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}

function RoleType(user: any, next: any): void{
    if(getRole() == user.role_portal){
        next('/redirect');
    } else {
        next('/');
    }
}

export { guardAuth };
```

I tried changing the keycloak init options and making guards for my routes, so I can check is has a token, but they also doesnt seem to work. I expect to have a flow where some pages are public and other are protected by keycloak

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have setup keycloak in my Vue.js app. I have two pages that are public and the rest of them are private and accessed after keycloak authentication.

```
    import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
    import useStore from "./store";
    
    const initOptions = {
      realm: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_REALM_NAME,
      clientId: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      url: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_SERVER_URL,
      "public-client": true,
      "verify-token-audience": false,
    };
    
    const keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions);
    
    async function initKeycloak() {
      const store = useStore();
    
      await keycloak
        .init({onLoad: "check-sso", redirectUri: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI})
        .then(async (auth) => {
          if (!auth) {
            store.unauthenticate();
          } else {
            await store.authenticate();
            if (keycloak.token) {
              store.token = keycloak.token;
              store.userRoles = keycloak.tokenParsed.realm_access.roles;
              window.localStorage.setItem("keycloakToken", keycloak.token);
            }
          }
        });
      setInterval(() => {
        keycloak
          .updateToken(70)
          .then((refreshed) => {
            if (refreshed) {
              store.token = keycloak.token;
              window.localStorage.setItem("keycloakToken", keycloak.token);
              console.info("Token refreshed" + refreshed);
            } else {
              console.warn(
                "Token not refreshed, valid for " +
                  Math.round(
                    keycloak.tokenParsed.exp +
                      keycloak.timeSkew -
                      new Date().getTime() / 1000
                  ) +
                  " seconds"
              );
            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            console.error("Failed to refresh token");
          });
      }, 3000);
    }
    
    export async function keycloakLogin() {
      keycloak.login();
    }
    
    // keycloak logout
    var logoutOptions = {redirectUri: import.meta.env.VITE_KEYCLOAK_REDIRECT_URI};
    
    function keycloakLogout() {
      keycloak
        .logout(logoutOptions)
        .then((success) => {
          console.log("--> log: logout success ", success);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("--> log: logout error ", error);
        });
    }
```

I'm not sure why you're using the `KeycloakInstance` maybe you've declared it on top of the file. I'm just using the `keycloakLogin` method on my landing page which is public and has the login button.

On click of the `login` button the `keycloakLogin` method is called and it redirects to the `auth server`. And after successful authentication it redirects to the `redirectUri` which is present in my `.env`.

I hope this helps.